# Connecting an arbitrary number of pins to pin holes without soldering?

Tags: pins

I want to avoid soldering for health reasons. I have no well-ventilated open area in my apartment. For a board/modules that have no pins but only holes, how can I connect pins to the holes without soldering?

For certain popular hardware like Raspberry Pi Zero, there seems to be something called "hammer header"

[image]

but the problem is those have a fixed, pre-determined number of pins, not individual pins. So, if a hardware has 5 holes instead of 20 holes, that thing cannot be used. Is there a hammer header for a single pin? So that if the hardware has 5 holes I would just use 5 of them. I have searched the Internet, but no result. Also, the "hammer header" itself seems to be rare. I could not find a single online store in my country that sells it.

Some existing answer mentioned "Pomona minigrabber", but that thing seems to be temporary. That is, I cannot move the device (it looks that it will fall off). So, that is probably not the answer I want.

A secondary, less-important question, but if I installed hammer pin headers (seems like one has to hit it with an actual hammer to install it), can I un-install (remove) the headers?

Comment: Do you have a medical condition that precludes soldering, or are you just under the impression that the (few) fumes are dangerous in some way?

Comment: The working principle behind those hammer heads might be cold welding. If that's the case they will form an atomic bond with the holes and they can't be removed without damage. I also can't understand your concerns about soldering. Just make those few solder joints outside if you are really scared. You can also use flux-less solder and colophony as a flux. Colophony is completely natural...

Comment: @Majenko According to my research, the fume from the coating of the wire seems to stuck in the lung once inhaled and accumulated, causing asthma or other diseases. ( https://www.asthma.org.uk/advice/understanding-asthma/types/occupational-asthma/ "Electronics and assembly industries expose people to irritants from fumes from rosin-based solder flux.") So, if possible I want to avoid it.

Comment: Do you *have* asthma? Rosin only causes minor irritation in people who are already susceptible. And they don't *actually* know if it's the rosin at all (rosin is a food additive and perfectly safe for ingestion). And soldering headers has no wire coating... I have been soldering for over 30 years in enclosed spaces with no noticeable effects. If you are that paranoid just get a Hakko FA-400.

Comment: @Majenko No, I do not have asthma. But a popular YouTube video said that the effect is cumulative and the symptoms may not appear for years until they do ( https://youtu.be/EGdlM48eDbA?t=108 ). I had search for solder wire that has no flux or soldering without flux, etc, but I could not find any result, so I thought all solder wires had that coating.

Comment: Never believe anything you see on social media!!! Soldering is perfectly safe. If it weren't all electronic engineers would be dead.

Comment: Do you have a exhaust fan in the bathroom or kitchen that vents to the outside of the building? Perhaps a piece of flexible dryer vent piping could be connected to the outside of the fan housing then be used to remove the fumes/gasses. Alternate solutions: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/161139/which-are-the-safety-recommendations-for-soldering

Comment: Maybe if you spend all day every day soldering and breathing fumes.  A small exposure from a hobby project isn’t going to hurt you.  STOP getting your science from YouTube.  They’ll let any idiot say anything they want there.  It’s not a reliable source.

Comment: If you are too afraid, electronics may be the wrong hobby for you :D ...sry

Comment: Rosin fumes are not toxic. Rosin is edible. It's used as a food additive. Rosin fumes can be an irritant (and *only* an irritant) to people with underlying breathing issues. They are far less harmful than an open fire in your living room, or walking along a pavement next to a busy road.

Comment: @VE7JRO I have a kitchen hood, of course, but I suspected that if I use it for soldering, bad substances from soldering might stick to the hood and might fall from the hood to foods when I cook next time.

Comment: @SimSon It is more like a necessity than a hobby, because I often cannot find an off-the-shelf electronic product that does what I want to do. Most existing products are dumb. For example, I cannot find an existing product that can switch between multiple 3.5mm audio jacks that can be controlled by an API.

Comment: "Electronics and assembly industries" refers to factory work constantly soldering pre-arranged parts, 15 welds/min is common, often 10 hours a day 6 days a week. In other words, one week of factory soldering (50k+ joins) is about the same as a lifetime of hobby soldering. You could use solder paste and a spare toaster oven run outside if paranoid. You might also be able to spot-weld small wires to gold through holes, but you'd have to be very very careful and precise.

Comment: "Bad substances from the soldering" will not fall from the hood into your food. Many devices are also available w/ pre-soldered headers. The likely reason there aren't any USB-/WiFi-controlled 3.5mm audio-jack-only switchers is because essentially nobody needs that.

Comment: Here's an older answer that is related that may offer some help: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/249140/how-can-i-make-connection-on-pcb-circuit-board-holes-without-solder-for-proto

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you already have seen, there are not many options to contact such boards without soldering, because **they are meant to be soldered**. Those hammer headers are an option. When you find a seller for your country, it should also have these in different sizes/numbers of pins.

Though contacting the board with the pins is not the only problem, you may face. As long as you are experimenting, the typical breadboard is often enough. But when you want to make something more permanent, reliable, current thirsty or noise sensitive, a breadboard is a bad choice. In that case you would also need to solder. Soldering is just a very integral part of electronics.

---

As others have wrote in the comments, I would also consider soldering as a hobbyist as safe, especially, when you take some precautions. A "well ventilated area" can be a simple room with the window open and a small fan directed to the working place, so that the fumes don't directly go up your nose. That is already a very big improvement, which is also rather cheap. That's also about what the woman does in the video, that you linked. And washing your hands after soldering is also a good measure. (I'm doing soldering the described way for about 15 years now, without any health issues)

In the video, that you linked, they say, that the fumes are toxic and their effect adds up. Letting aside, that they don't back it up with any data and I cannot either, they also don't talk about the amount of solder work, that they consider here. As an electronics beginner you most likely will just solder very rarely for getting pin headers on boards or maybe contacting a motor. The main work most likely will still be done on the breadboard. So here the exposure is so small, that you don't need to consider more than the above safety measures. These will also last rather long, as you get more profound in electronics. And when keeping up that hobby, you maybe wanna invest in a more professional filter system, as you are doing more solder work.

Doing electronics while being that scared of soldering will not be much fun. For the start you might get away by only buying presoldered boards. But very fast you will run against walls with this. Not a good start for a beginner.

But in the end it's your own decision. You have all right to be afraid of solder fumes, though that just might disqualify electronics as a hobby for you.

> if I installed hammer pin headers (seems like one has to hit it with an actual hammer to install it), can I un-install (remove) the headers?

That depends on the pin headers, but most likely no. You would need physical force to get them off. And the pads on a PCB are not very strong. They are made to be soldered, not for tearing the pins off without any damage. But why would you want to remove the headers? You only very rarely solder wires directly to the board for connecting with other parts. Either you solder it onto another PCB (where the pin headers come in handy), or you use a female header on a PCB or a cable for making the connection temporary. For example all my small Arduinos get pin headers soldered to them, so I can put them onto my own PCBs via female headers on the PCB. With that I can also disconnect or replace the Arduino if I need to.

Answer (score 1):

I placed the arduino on a breadboard with the pins on the breadboard 1 pinhole further apart than it 'should' be, this way you can press the arduino down and the arduino will fasten itself in place.

[image]

Comment: I do not know who downvoted this but this is actually quite an interesting idea. So, you put two unsoldered pin headers on the breadboard but one-hole-width wider, and use the tension of the pins when you put the Arduino's holes on those holes.  PS: It may be better to embed the image in the answer itself, not as a link.

Answer (score 0):

Why not get a fume extractor, there are all types, some even have filters. Simply do a google search for "fume extractor", on my first try I got 587,000 hits. The price is all all over the map even for the same model.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where a sensor I bought came with holes and the pins not attached. I do not have any soldering skills and searched for a solution. I ended up wrapping tinfoil around each of the small pins to increas their diameter and jamed it in the sensor's holes. As far as I can tell, it is working. It is a bit tidious and is clearly not a long term solution but ended up working at least to test my sensor and set it up.
I couldn't find any solution online without having to buy something else so here you go, if any one is looking for a quick solution with house hold items. Hope it can help any one in need.

(make sure the tinfoil is not in contact with other pins or other metalic part of your sensor as it could cause shorts.... be careful not to damage your devices :) )